# How to Normalize data?

Tags: anova, covariance, normalization, multivariate-normal-distribution

In a study, the baseline data are recorded (blood pressure, BP1) prior to the experiment (watching a horror film). After the experiment, the data (BP2) are collected again. The problem is that not all participants arrived in the lab with the same level of blood pressure. Therefore it is important to normalize the data before doing the analysis.

I have seen some researchers apply log to standardize the data. I am not clear what log does and the procedure involved.

What is the best solution in this case? 
Please advise the statistical test that needs to be performed in this case to normalize the data.

Comment: You are looking for a difference in readings before and after a treatment (i.e. watching a film), yes? If that is the case, have you tried a simple  within-group test to compare the means?

Comment: Well, comparing the means will not help me determine the dependent var (BP2). I am looking for ways to ensure that the BP2 data are not confounded by the BP1. That is why I would like to know how to normalize the BP2 data.

Answer (score 1):

This question may be approached in several different ways.

As pointed out by dnbwise you could simply use changes in blood pressure ([BP] at time 2 minus BP at time 1), or ratios (BP at time 2 divided by BP at time 1). Otherwise, you could simply run a paired t test or paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Other meaningful strategies could be to create a bootstrapped estimate of BP at time 2.

I would favor though using a regression approach in which you have BP at time 1 as independent variable and BP at time 2 as independent variable.

This approach is eminently feasible with several different approaches in many packages (eg ['gee'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gee/gee.pdf) in R), and its great strength is that you can upgrade it as you need adding terms for other independent variables (eg age, gender, movie title), and so forth.

Comment: If I use the simple method BP_Time2 - BP_Time1, I believe I can still use it as my dependent var (since BP_Time2 is supposed to be my dependent var). Otherwise, is there a way to normalize the data using log. I am very curious to know. Thank you

Comment: You can use the delta as dependent and baseline BP as independent, but again, you will have to extrapolate the delta to the sample (or population) average to make predictions, so I would favor a standard regression approach. I would not use logarithm transformation. Indeed, I think you use normalization in a different sense than the one which is referred when people say 'normalization with logarithm transformation'. This has to do with reshaping the distribution in a more Gaussian shape.

Comment: The log-transformation is widely used in biomedical and psychosocial research to deal with *skewed data*. [This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4120293/) highlights serious problems and recommends methods that are not dependent on the distribution of the data, such as generalized estimating equations (GEE).